# How to write a custom flume OG sink

Tags: rabbitmq, flume

We're using flume and I need to collect some log messages into rabbitmq. I found a source [implementation](https://github.com/stampy88/flume-amqp-plugin) that reads messages from rabbitmq, but I couldn't find a sink that can write messages into rabbit. So I was thinking about writing one myself. Looking at sample implementations like [logsandra](https://github.com/pantheon-systems/logsandra) made me think it shouldn't be too difficult.

However I couldn't find any documentation on how to write a custom sink.
I didn't find a maven repo for the flume jars, or setup instructions on how to deploy a custom sink.

Can anyone share his experience, or better, point me to an existing tutorial.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eventually we wrote one ourselves, and open sourced it - https://github.com/kenshoo/flume-rabbitmq-sink

there's a cloudera repo now  https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/Using+the+CDH3+Maven+Repository (there wasn't when I asked)

And flume user guide now explains well how to configure a custom plugin

http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/flume/UserGuide/index.html#_extending_via_sink_source_decorator_plugins